# How to properly use jpeg_mem_dest with and without a std::vector

Tags: c++, c, c++11, jpeg, libjpeg

I've come across this problem while searching for how to write to a buffer instead of a file and I have trouble finding a good example.

This is what the jpeglib.h says but I'm unsure on how to use this.

```
/* Data source and destination managers: memory buffers. */
EXTERN(void) jpeg_mem_dest JPP((j_compress_ptr cinfo,
                   unsigned char ** outbuffer,
                   unsigned long * outsize));
```

In the ***example.c*** we set the data destination at ***Step 2*** so how would one use this here if we already have a `std::vector<unsigned char> buffer` that holds RGB values.

```
/* Step 2: specify data destination (eg, a file) */
/* Note: steps 2 and 3 can be done in either order. */
    jpeg_mem_dest(&cinfo, /*WHAT GOES HERE*/, /*WHAT GOES HERE*/);
```

After this is done, what changes do we make to ***Step 5*** so that we write in the ***same*** buffer where our decompressed RGB values were?

```
/* Step 5: while (scan lines remain to be written) */
/*           jpeg_write_scanlines(...); */
```

Did I miss something? I really appreciate any help, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have moved on but the following works for anyone else looking.

```
struct Result{
  unsigned char* buf;
  unsigned long size;
}
Result result;
// ..Here allocate the buffer and initialize the size
// before using in jpeg_mem_dest.  Or it will allocate for you
// and you have to clean up.
jpeg_mem_dest(&cinfo, &result->buf, &result->size);
// use buffer
free(result->buf); // <- of course depending on the way the buffer was allocated
```

If you are working with a std::vector you may be able to pass the raw buffer using something like &myVec[0] or myVec.data() since c++11 (but think I may have had trouble with that).  A workaround is to use raw buffers and just copy/insert if not performance critical.

```
// Copy based.  Could also just buffer.insert if not preallocated using resize.
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer;
budder.resize(result->size())
std::copy(result->buf
        , result->buf + result->size
        , buffer.begin());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `jpeg_mem_dest` to write directly to a `std::vector`, since it allocates/manages its own memory.  You could copy that memory to a `std::vector` afterwards, but that's of course expensive.

If you want to write directly to an `std::vector` you have to manage it yourself by setting up the `jpeg_destination_mgr *dest` structure inside your `jpeg_compress_struct`.

```cpp
struct jpeg_destination_mgr {
  JOCTET *next_output_byte;     /* => next byte to write in buffer */
  size_t free_in_buffer;        /* # of byte spaces remaining in buffer */

  void (*init_destination) (j_compress_ptr cinfo);
  boolean (*empty_output_buffer) (j_compress_ptr cinfo);
  void (*term_destination) (j_compress_ptr cinfo);
};
```

You need to set up the `init_destination`, `empty_output_buffer`, and `term_destination` callbacks and set `next_output_byte` and `free_in_buffer` according to the situation.

- `init_destination` is for initialization and doesn't need to do anything special when writing to `std::vector`
- `empty_output_buffer` is called when the supplied buffer is full (i.e. `free_in_buffer==0`); when writing to `std::vector` you can grow the buffer and return the new, free memory by setting `next_output_byte` and `free_in_buffer`
- `term_destination` is called when compression is done, but it's possible (indeed, likely) that the last buffer isn't completely full (i.e. `free_in_buffer>0`); when writing to `std::vector` this can be used to resize the vector to the final size

```cpp
struct stdvector_destination_mgr
{
    struct jpeg_destination_mgr pub;        // public fields
    std::vector< uint8_t >* vec = nullptr;  // destination vector
};

void init_stdvector_destination( j_compress_ptr /*cinfo*/ )
{
    // Nothing to do
}

boolean
empty_stdvector_output_buffer( j_compress_ptr cinfo )
{
    auto* dest = reinterpret_cast< stdvector_destination_mgr* >( cinfo->dest );

    // Double vector capacity
    const auto currentSize = dest->vec->size( );
    dest->vec->resize( currentSize * 2 );

    // Point to newly allocated data
    dest->pub.next_output_byte = dest->vec->data( ) + currentSize;
    dest->pub.free_in_buffer = currentSize;

    return TRUE;
}

void
term_stdvector_destination( j_compress_ptr cinfo )
{
    auto* dest = reinterpret_cast< stdvector_destination_mgr* >( cinfo->dest );

    // Resize vector to number of bytes actually used
    const auto used_bytes = dest->vec->capacity( ) - dest->pub.free_in_buffer;
    dest->vec->resize( used_bytes );
}

void
jpeg_stdvector_dest( j_compress_ptr cinfo, std::vector< uint8_t >& vec )
{
    if ( cinfo->dest == NULL )
    {
        cinfo->dest = (struct jpeg_destination_mgr*)( *cinfo->mem->alloc_small )( (j_common_ptr)cinfo, JPOOL_PERMANENT, sizeof( stdvector_destination_mgr ) );
    }

    auto* dest = reinterpret_cast< stdvector_destination_mgr* >( cinfo->dest );
    dest->pub.init_destination = init_stdvector_destination;
    dest->pub.empty_output_buffer = empty_stdvector_output_buffer;
    dest->pub.term_destination = term_stdvector_destination;

    // Set output buffer and initial size
    dest->vec = &vec;
    dest->vec->resize( 4096 );

    // Initialize public buffer ptr and size
    dest->pub.next_output_byte = dest->vec->data( );
    dest->pub.free_in_buffer = dest->vec->size( );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to look at the documentation.
But outbuffer is an unsigned char **. So almost certainly the function
will call malloc, then set outbuffer to the result.

```
/*
   skeleton code - it won't be this exactly but will
   look like this.
*/ 
EXTERN(void) jpeg_mem_dest JPP((j_compress_ptr cinfo,
                   unsigned char ** outbuffer,
                   unsigned long * outsize))
{
   int width, height;
   unsigned char *rgba;

   getimagesize(cinfo, &width, & height);
   rgba = malloc(width * height * 4);

   decompress(cinfo, rgba);

   *outbuffer = rgba;
   *outsize = width * height *4;
}
```

So to call

```
unsigned char *rgba;
unsigned long size;
std::vector<unsigned char> buffer.
jpeg_mem_dest(jpegdata, &rgba, &size);
if(size > 0)
{
   buffer.resize(size);
   for(i=0;i<size;i++)
     buffer[i] = rgba[i];
   free(rgba);
}
```

Comment: I can't get it to work. Either get a Write Access Violation or weird crashes without a description. Could you please provide a working example? Would be much appreciated. Also is there a way I could bypass the rgba array and directly write to my `std::vector`?

Comment: I don't have the library.I can't compile a working example. is it crashing in the call or accessing the buffers? Maybe you just need to initialise rgba to zero. Look up the function interface spec.

Comment: Doesn't make sense.